# How to perform a group by on a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I would like to perform a group by on a list and calculate the average.

Here is the list:

```
[['Profit ratio', [[2016, 5], [2017, 10], [2018, 5], [2016, 5], [2017, 20], [2018, 10]]]
```

After grouping and averaging I would like the following:

```
[['Profit ratio', [[2016, 5], [2017, 15], [2018, 7.5]]
```

I have tried doing this with a loop, that gathers the years and appends the numbers to the end and then calculates the average. Is there a better approach?

Comment: That's how I'd do it. You could be "fancy" with `sorted` and `groupby` but I don't know why you would.

Comment: your syntax is invalid, can you double check and correct the level of nested lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this seems fairly straightforward. Assuming your data is:

```py
data_with_headers = [['Profit ratio',
     [[2016, 5],
      [2017, 10],
      [2018, 5],
      [2016, 5],
      [2017, 20],
      [2018, 10]]]]
```

And that there's more values here than just "Profit ratio," you could do something like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

result = []
for header, values in data_with_headers:
    raw_data = defaultdict(list)
    for year, value in values:
        raw_data[year].append(value)
    result.append([header, [[year, sum(values)/len(values)] for year, values in raw_data.items()]])

assert result == [['Profit ratio', [[2016, 5.0], [2017, 15.0], [2018, 7.5]]]]
```

Comment: Note that your data structure does seem distinctly _wrong_ though. You're using a bunch of lists which are idiomatically homogenous collections where you maybe want tuples instead? Indeed these seem to mostly be key-value pairs, which imply you should instead be using a dictionary.